# The given json data was not valid json

Tags: swift

Here is my struct

```
struct Players: Codable {
    let players: [Player]
}

// MARK: - Player
struct Player: Codable {
    let name: String
    let number, gp, gs, min: Double
    let fgm, fga, fg3, fg3A: Double
    let ft, fta, pts, oreb: Double
    let dreb, pf, ast, to: Double
    let stl, blk: Double

}
```

Here is my json

```
 "Players" : {
        [
            {
                "name" : "Player",
                "number" : 0,
                "gp" : 0,
                "gs" : 0,
                "min" : 0,
                "fgm" : 0,
                "fga" : 0,
                "fg3" : 0,
                "fg3a" : 0,
                "ft" : 0,
                "fta" : 0,
                "pts" : 0,
                "oreb" : 0,
                "dreb" : 0,
                "pf" : 0,
                "ast" : 0,
                "to" : 0,
                "stl" : 0,
                "blk" : 0
            },
            {
                "name" : "Player",
                "number" : 0,
                "gp" : 0,
                "gs" : 0,
                "min" : 0,
                "fgm" : 0,
                "fga" : 0,
                "fg3" : 0,
                "fg3a" : 0,
                "ft" : 0,
                "fta" : 0,
                "pts" : 0,
                "oreb" : 0,
                "dreb" : 0,
                "pf" : 0,
                "ast" : 0,
                "to" : 0,
                "stl" : 0,
                "blk" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is my code

```
    do {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Players.self, from: data)
        print(decoded)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

And it keeps returning that I have invalid Json. I am not exactly sure what to about this but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward: your “JSON” isn’t in fact JSON, exactly as the error message is telling you.

Comment: There’s online linters where you can test your json for validity, https://jsonlint.com/ is one example

Answer (score 0):

Because your json is invalid json file.
JSON starts with { and ends with }. Your doesnt.
Also your json has { on wrong place after "Player". You defined array so it should go something like this:

```json
{ "Players" : [
            {
                "name" : "Player",
                "number" : 0,
                "gp" : 0,
                "gs" : 0,
                "min" : 0,
                "fgm" : 0,
                "fga" : 0,
                "fg3" : 0,
                "fg3a" : 0,
                "ft" : 0,
                "fta" : 0,
                "pts" : 0,
                "oreb" : 0,
                "dreb" : 0,
                "pf" : 0,
                "ast" : 0,
                "to" : 0,
                "stl" : 0,
                "blk" : 0
            },
            {
                "name" : "Player",
                "number" : 0,
                "gp" : 0,
                "gs" : 0,
                "min" : 0,
                "fgm" : 0,
                "fga" : 0,
                "fg3" : 0,
                "fg3a" : 0,
                "ft" : 0,
                "fta" : 0,
                "pts" : 0,
                "oreb" : 0,
                "dreb" : 0,
                "pf" : 0,
                "ast" : 0,
                "to" : 0,
                "stl" : 0,
                "blk" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

PS. this is recreation of assumption, but i assume you wanted Players to be an array

This is valid json

```json
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
```

This is not valid json

```json
"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null
```

Also for arrays, they are defined with `[`
So a valid array would be

```json
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
```

And this will not be a valid json array

```json
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":{["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in json is `"Players"` and key in the `struct Players` is `"players"`.

```
struct Players: Codable {
    let players: [Player]
}
```

You can add a custom value for CodingKeys like this -

```
struct Players: Codable {
    let players: [Player]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case players = "Players"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Players" to be an array of objects, then move the first bracket to before "Players" like so:

```
{
  "Players" : [
    {
        "name" : "Player",
        "number" : 0,
        "gp" : 0,
        "gs" : 0,
        "min" : 0,
        "fgm" : 0,
        "fga" : 0,
        "fg3" : 0,
        "fg3a" : 0,
        "ft" : 0,
        "fta" : 0,
        "pts" : 0,
        "oreb" : 0,
        "dreb" : 0,
        "pf" : 0,
        "ast" : 0,
        "to" : 0,
        "stl" : 0,
        "blk" : 0
    },
    {
        "name" : "Player",
        "number" : 0,
        "gp" : 0,
        "gs" : 0,
        "min" : 0,
        "fgm" : 0,
        "fga" : 0,
        "fg3" : 0,
        "fg3a" : 0,
        "ft" : 0,
        "fta" : 0,
        "pts" : 0,
        "oreb" : 0,
        "dreb" : 0,
        "pf" : 0,
        "ast" : 0,
        "to" : 0,
        "stl" : 0,
        "blk" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```